# Auto-Generating namespace for the class added in a folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I have take App_Code folder to my solution and added two more folders saying Business and Data. Now when I add a class to these folders the class added should be under the  same namespace as name of the folder.
I,e If I add a class under Business that class should come under Business namespace. 
similarly, If I add a class under Data that class should come under Data namespace.

I am bit new to this. Please help me in getting this done.

Comment: what namespaces do you get when you add files?

Comment: I am not getting any namespace. I am just getting the class structure. I need namespace along with the class structure

Comment: How are you adding the new classes?

Comment: Right Click on Business Folder-->Add New Item-->Select Class1.cs and click on Add button . This is the way I am adding the classes.

Comment: if you right click your project and select properties, do you have a default namespace set?

Comment: I tried doing the step of right click on project I didn't find any such option thummunkeys. I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I think what might have gone on here is that you were in the Folder View of the Solution Explorer when you made your classes.

If you click the icon to the right of the home icon in the Solution Explorer Toolbar (see the image below), then you should be able to switch back to the Solution View. Now when you add a class the correct namespace will be generated automatically in the template. A lot of other convenient features are not available when making new classes in the Folder View, too, not exactly sure why!

["Switch between solutions and available views"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eYw0.png)

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and couldn't find any solutions in all my googling, so I felt I had to answer.